# Replace values in a logical vector to factor

Tags: r, levels

This is my first question here, don't judge me :)

In `R`, I've got a logical vector. I want to transform this logical values into levels. For example, for `TRUE` I want to put "Sweet", for `FALSE`I want to put "Spicy". Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Soberbio, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert the logical to `factor` by specifying the `levels` and the corresponding `labels`

```
factor(v1, levels = c(TRUE, FALSE), labels = c('Sweet', 'Spicy'))
#[1] Sweet Spicy Sweet Sweet
#Levels: Sweet Spicy
```

---

Or convert the logical to numeric index and use that to replace a vector of values

```
factor(c("Spicy", "Sweet")[1 + v1])
```

#### data

```
 v1 <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
```

Comment: Solved, thank you! I didn't know about ```levels```argument in that function. I'm actually new in R.